# Remove duplicates from Json response flutter with some condition in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get json without duplicates with the proximy expiry date

```
var productos= "[{      "NAME": "STRAWBERRY MILK",      "EXPIRYDATE": "2022-01-01"  },  {       "NAME": "COOKIES",      "EXPIRYDATE": "2023-01-28"  },  {       "NAME": "STRAWBERRY MILK",      "EXPIRYDATE": "2022-01-11"  },  {       "NAME": "STRAWBERRY MILK",      "EXPIRYDATE": "2022-12-11"  }]"


List<ProductModels> productsJson = productModelsFromJson(productos); List<ProductModels> clearProductsJson =[]; productsJson.forEach((item) {
           //remove duplicates clearProductsJson=item; });
```

```
How can i achieve this?
```

[
{
"NAME": "COOKIES",
"EXPIRYDATE": "2023-01-28"
},
{
"NAME": "STRAWBERRY MILK",
"EXPIRYDATE": "2022-12-11"
}

]

Comment: Are you using any model class?

Comment: Yes but just have Strings as parameters  

factory ProductModels.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductModels(
        name: json["NAME"],
        expirydate: json["EXPIRYDATE"],
    );

Comment: for `EXPIRYDATE` it seems taking  latest date

Answer (score 0):

here is a function that remove maps that have same **NAME** :

```
   List removeDuplicates(
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> decodedJsonContainingAllMaps) {
  Map map = {};

  for (int index = 0; index < decodedJsonContainingAllMaps.length; index += 1) {
    Map currentMapData = decodedJsonContainingAllMaps[index];

    if (map[currentMapData["NAME"]] != null) {
      continue;
    }
    map.addAll({currentMapData["NAME"]: currentMapData});
  }
  return map.values.toList();
}
```

use it in your case like this :

```
List decodedJson = JsonDecode(productos);
List listButWithoutDuplication = removeDuplicates(decodedJson);
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I get the record with the same name and the latest date?